# Checking if the job exists without looping through all the jobs

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I would like my application to prevent from adding identical jobs on my Windows service. That means if the job key exists, I would like to warn the user about it. I am using my scheduler's `CheckExists()` method like this:

```
IScheduler sched = scheduler.GetScheduler();
IJobDetail postbagjob = JobBuilder.Create<PostbagJob>()
    .WithIdentity(jobName, jobGroup)
    .UsingJobData("CampaignId", campaignId.ToString())
    .UsingJobData("CampaignType", campaignType)
    .Build();
ITrigger postbagJobTrigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity(triggerName, triggerGroup)
    .WithCronSchedule(cron)
    .StartAt(DateTime.Now)
    .Build();
if (sched.CheckExists(postbagjob.Key))
{
    MsgBox.Show("Job already exists!");
}
else
{
    MsgBox.Show("It's ok. You can schedule this job.");
}
```

The problem is this function receives a `JobKey` as the argument. And by that I assume that the job should already be created. So the code above will give an exception. Is there a way to check if a specific `JobKey` exists before we create a job?

I know that a way of doing it is to loop through all the jobs. But can we do it without it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can create a `JobKey` without creating a job. `JobKey` has both public constructor and public factory methods.

```
var jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, jobGroup);
if (sched.CheckExists(jobKey)) //...
```

Comment: FYI - in my case I needed to use: await sched.CheckExists(job.Key) ... but the principle remains untouched. Thanks.